# How to measure the relation between two random variables that are not linearly correlated?

Tags: correlation, python, sampling, covariance

Sometimes it appears that the covariance is not sufficient to express how much two random variables are related.

Bellow, I have draw random samples from a multivariate normal distribution with two random variables X and Y.

**First case :** Cov(X,Y) $\simeq$ 0
[image: Dispersion of two random variables X and Y]

**Second case :** Cor(X,Y) $\simeq$ 1
[image]

**Third case:** Cor(X,Y) $\simeq$ 0, ok but then is there a better metric than correlation in this case ?

[image]

*Remark : Here the python code to draw the examples :*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s1 = np.random.normal(0, 5, 500)
s2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 500)

f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2)

axarr[0, 0].scatter(s1, s2)
axarr[0, 0].set_title('X,Y ')

axarr[0, 1].scatter(s1, s1+s1)
axarr[0, 1].set_title('X, X+X')

axarr[1, 0].scatter(s1, s1*s1)
axarr[1, 0].set_title('X,X*X')

axarr[1, 1].scatter(s1, s1+s2)
axarr[1, 1].set_title('X,X+Y')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Covariance is a linear measure. The metric works well for your first and second case.

Comment: Yes the two first cases are linear so it works well, is there an other metric for non linear cases ?

Comment: With 'how to measure the relation' you mean not 'measuring/determining the *shape* of the relation' but rather measuring 'whether there is any relation at all' (where relation means difference from $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$, or difference from independence)?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I don't know this notation, what do your function $f_{X,Y}$ mean?
Yes, I would like to verify if "there is any relation at all" between the two RV $X$ and $Y$ since I already know that $Y$ is equal to $X^2$ in the third case.

Comment: @FlorentJousse with $f_{X,Y}$ I mean the joint probability density function. That formula is a way to define independence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Two_random_variables). If that is what you mean than you could use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation , but maybe it is something else that you want.

Comment: thank you, let me check that, I'm not yet familiar to all these terms.